# Looping Multiple Variables in R

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have a data frame with firm level data such as revenue, profits and costs. I would need to loop through 3 variables - revenue, profit and costs over this code:

`datagroup %>% group_by(treat) %>% summarise(n = n(), mean = mean(profit), std_error = sd(profit) / sqrt(n))`

Basically, I would run the code for revenue and costs by replacing the variable profit. Could you assist? I tried for loops but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in a loop with the column name as string, then convert it to `symbol`, evaluate (`!!`) and get the `mean`

```
library(tidyverse)
c("revenue", "costs") %>%
   map(~ datagroup %>% 
         group_by(treat) %>%
          summarise(n = n(), 
          !! str_c("mean_", .x) := mean(!! rlang::sym(.x)), # convert to symbol 
         !! str_c("std_error_", .x) := sd(!! rlang::sym(.x)) / sqrt(n)))
```

---

We can also do this with `summarise_at`

```
c("revenue", "costs") %>%
   map(~ datagroup %>% 
         group_by(treat) %>%
         group_by(n = n(), add = TRUE) %>%             
          summarise_at(vars(.x), 
              list(mean = ~ mean(.x),
                   std_error = ~ sd(.x)/sqrt(first(n)))))
```

The output will be a `list` of `data.frame`s

Comment: Thank you. However, i met with this error:   Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                  std_error = sd(!! rlang::sym(.x)) / sqrt(n))
c"

Comment: @Jackson  have you sorted the error.  I think you need a closing `)` for the `map(`

Comment: Oh yes i did! apologies. Thank you so very much! Could I ask further if I want to label the names of the mean and std_error by the variables e.g. mean_revenue, mean_costs, can the above code be refined further? Thank you so much

Comment: @Jackson Try with the second method

Comment: @Jackson  i edited the first method (sorry, coulnd't test it witout a reproducible example), I hope it works

Comment: @Jackson With `mtcars`, it is working fine `mtcars %>% group_by(vs) %>% summarise(n = n(), !! str_c("mean_", "qsec") := mean(!! rlang::sym("qsec")))`

Comment: Hi @akrun, could I ask how do you "force" combine the lists together into 1 list after this? Thank you!

Comment: @Jackson Did you meant one data.frame?  Replace `map` with `map_df`

Comment: Hi @akrun, yes. However, I would need it to have the same number of rows i.e., joining the lists together so the rows remain the same. `map_df` adds to both the rows and columns. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jackson Ok, in that case after the `map`, try `%>% reduce(full_join, by = "treat")`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to R, consider base R for multiple aggregate functions on multiple numeric columns via a `cbind` + `aggregate` + `do.call`:

```
do.call(data.frame, 
   aggregate(cbind(revenue, cost, profit) ~ treat, 
             datagroup, 
             function(x) c(n = length(x), 
                           mean = mean(x), 
                           std_error = sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))
                          )
   )
)
```